# Logistic regression cost function

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression, cost-function

In Aurelien Geron's  book I found this line

`This cost function makes sense because –log(t) grows very large when t approaches
 0, so the cost will be large if the model estimates a probability close to 0 for a positive instance, and it will also be very large if the model estimates a probability close to 1
for a negative instance. On the other hand, – log(t) is close to 0 when t is close to 1, so
the cost will be close to 0 if the estimated probability is close to 0 for a negative
instance or close to 1 for a positive instance, which is precisely what we want.`

What I dont get is, How will  the cost will be large if the model estimates a probability close to 0 for a positive instance, and it will also be very large if the model estimates a probability close to 1
for a negative instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cost function of the Logistic Regression derived via Maximum    Likelihood  Estimation: 
[image]
[image]

- **If y = 1 (positive):** i) cost = 0 if prediction is correct (i.e. h=1), ii) cost $\rightarrow \infty $ if $h_{\theta}(x)\rightarrow 0$.
- **If y = 0 (negative):** i) cost = 0 if prediction is correct (i.e. h=0), ii) cost $\rightarrow \infty$ if $(1-h_{\theta}(x))\rightarrow 0$.

The intuition is that larger mistakes should get larger penalties.
Further readings, [1](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~bboots3/CS4641-Fall2016/Lectures/Lecture6.pdf),[2](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logistic_regression.html),[3](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/neural-networks-deep-learning/logistic-regression-cost-function-yWaRd),[4](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html).

Comment: Yes, I get it. I was not able to digest, how the model penalises the cost function, whenever the difference between predicted and actual probablities are different.

Answer (score 3):

Not trying to oversimplify the answer, but simply get a calculator to compute these manually and you can see this in action:

If `t` is close to 1, lets just say that is 0.9999 for the example, then:
$$
-log(t) = -log(0.9999) = 0.000100005
$$

conversely,

If `t` is close to 0, lets just say that is 0.0001 for the example, then:
$$
-log(t) = -log(0.0001) = 9.21034
$$

So if the probability is high, the cost function returns a small, but if the probability is low, the cost function returns a (relatively) large number.

Perhaps I missed the point of your question, in which case, I apologize.